# MySQL Notifier High Cpu Load

Tags: mysql, cpu

I'm using Windows 10 and latest MySQL version Community Edition, configured as development machine. Recently when I was playing game, I've discovered that I have FPS drops every few seconds (about 5), overall system slow down, and high CPU usage spikes. After long investigation using Process Explorer, TaskMgr, then manually disabling services and startup applications, I've found that it is caused by MySQL Notifier, which causes services.exe to use high cpu usage about 20-50% of CPU. Workaround is to disable MySQL Notifier in Startup Management in Windows 10.

Why this happen, and how to fix it? Reinstallation didn't solve issue.
Does anyone have same problem?

Comment: I can confirm this behavior, still present. Took me hours to figure out the cause of the CPU load of services.exe. It's definitely MySQL Notifier.

Answer (score 2):

No application options appear to stop this issue. Only option so far is to disable/close MySQL Notifier
[Process Hacker showing services.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ddpsm.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Startup Management in Windows 10 is found my loading up Task Manager, and switching to the Start-up tab. From there you can locate MySQL Notified and change its status to Disabled.